# How to only import Hibernate specific annotations e.g. @CreationTimestamp @UpdateTimestamp?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee

In a pure JEE webapp i.e. packaged as a war/ear to be deployed on JBoss EAP 6.4.x how can I import in my pom.xml a minimal dependency to Hibernate annotations?

There used to be a hibernate-annotations.jar back in the days, but this artefact isn't updated since around 2010 or maybe 2008.

The reason is to use these Hibernate specific annotations (not supported in JPA) @CreationTimestamp and @UpdateTimestamp

Use case here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35448348

Comment: But if you add the annotations, you'd need to use hibernate as your JPA provider otherwise they'd be ignored - so you might as well add the whole of hibernate as a dependency.

Comment: Of course the JPA provider is Hibernate, JEE server is JBoss!!!